# how to get top ten result in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This delow query give me some error:

```
declare @date1 nvarchar(100) , @date2 nvarchar(100)

select @date1='2009-04-20', @date2='2009-05-20'

select top 10 t.VisitingCount , t.Page
    from (
           select  Count(Page) as VisitingCount,Page
               from scr_SecuristLog   
               where Date between @date1 and @date2  
                   and [user] in (select USERNAME             
                                      from scr_CustomerAuthorities
                                 )  
               group by Page order by [VisitingCount] desc 
         ) t
```

Error:

The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Something looks wrong here given the query structure and use of sub queries. May suggest that you provide the table structures involved to assist with the provision of a solution.

Comment: i change my question....

Comment: I really donn understand the use of ORDER BY here

Comment: nvarchar(100) for a date?! What's wrong with using DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME?

Answer (score 7):

I think you missed Comma

```
select top 10 t.VisitingCount , t.Page from
```

in above line after **t.VisitingCount**

Comment: c'mon... its not allowed to use ORDER BY in subqueries, please read ERROR message before posting the question :)

Comment: Prashant i need order by . How can i use it?

Answer (score 2):

pull the order by out of the derived table "t"

try this:

```
declare @date1 nvarchar(100) , @date2 nvarchar(100)

select @date1='2009-04-20', @date2='2009-05-20'

select top 10 t.VisitingCount , t.Page
    from (
           select  Count(Page) as VisitingCount,Page
               from scr_SecuristLog   
               where Date between @date1 and @date2  
                   and [user] in (select USERNAME             
                                      from scr_CustomerAuthorities
                                 )  
               group by Page
         ) t 
     order by [VisitingCount] desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @date1 nvarchar(100) , @date2 nvarchar(100)

select @date1='2009-04-20', @date2='2009-05-20'

select t.VisitingCount, t.Page from(
select top 10 Count(Page) as VisitingCount,Page from scr_SecuristLog   
where Date between @date1 and @date2  
and [user] in(select USERNAME             
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities )  
group by Page order by [VisitingCount] desc ) t order by t.VisitingCount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify some order by inside your inline view:

declare @date1 nvarchar(100) , @date2 nvarchar(100)

select @date1='2009-04-20', @date2='2009-05-20'

select top 10 t.VisitingCount , t.Page from(
select  Count(Page) as VisitingCount,Page from scr_SecuristLog
where Date between @date1 and @date2
and [user] in(select USERNAME
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities 
ORDER BY whatever-column(s)-you-need
)
group by Page order by [VisitingCount] desc ) t